# Simulink: add block in a for loop from script to the model

Tags: matlab, simulink

Through a script I am trying to create smaller moduls from the whole and complex model. I cut this modul and add it in a new model. That works.

In second step what I want to do is to add constant blocks according the number of the inputs. For the outputs I want to add terminator according the number of the outputs. Sure, in the end they have to be connected.

To add constant block I use the following command (it works):

`add_block('simulink/Commonly Used Blocks/Constant', 'my_model/Constant1')`

This has to work in a for-loop according that how many inputs exist.

To connect this constant blocks with the input (doenst work):

`add_line('my_model', 'Constant1', 'Input1')`

How can I achieve this in a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find a solution like below. It can add blocks and connect it

```
for i = 1:5; 
   add_block('simulink/Commonly Used Blocks/Constant', strcat('myModel/Input',num2str(i)));    
   add_line('myModel',strcat('Input',num2str(i),'/1'), strcat('block_name/',num2str(i)));
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at the example in the [add_line](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/add_line.html) documentation more closely.  You should be using,

```
add_line('my_model', 'ConstantBlockName/1', 'YourBlockName/1')
```

Change the `1` in the above code to reflect which input or output of the block you are connecting to.

Comment: Thanks, this was a mistake in the code. Now it works fine. But my question is how can I do it in a for-loop?

Comment: You change the block name and/or port number each time through the loop.

Comment: Please see above my solution for my own question. It works fine and you can try it if you are interested. (I would be glad if you vote my solution-> thanks)